# create on check configuration base on sun checks global

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I'm nerved by the default checks "sun checks global" performes within the eclipse plugin checkstyle. So I try to remove the checks for line length and constants. As far as I know, it seems not possible for "sun checks global".

So does anyone knows how to create my own checkstyle configuration (without starting from the beginning) by using the settings of "sun checks (global)"?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Checkstyle preferences page (`Window->Preferences->Checkstyle`). Select the "`Sun Checks`" or "`Sun Checks (Eclipse)`" entry (whichever you want to start with) and click the `Copy` button.

You'll then be able to name and modify the copy. You'll also need to either set it as the default or set it on individual projects.

Comment: A copy of local ckeck configuration is possible, but for "Sun Checks (Eclipse)" or  "Sun Checks (Eclipse)" they do not exist! -> Do you know where to find These configs, so I only have to include them?

Comment: Are you looking under the project properties instead of the main Eclipse preferences page (Window->Preferences->Checkstyle)?